# Multiple rows in SQL Server Triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm wanting to write a trigger to audit inserts, updates and deletes of rows of a table in SQL Server. According to MSDN, SQL Server triggers run "per table" not "per row" as they do in Oracle and Sqlite.

Does this mean that you would ONLY ever get multiple records in the 'inserted' and 'deleted'  temp-tables on the following scenarios

1. A SINGLE insert statement, inside or outside a transaction, resulted in multiple rows being created.
2. A SINGLE update statement, inside or outside a transaction, resulted in multiple updates.
3. A SINGLE delete statement, inside or outside a transaction, resulted in multiple deletions of rows.

Is there any other scenario when a trigger might be called having "inserted" or "deleted" > 1 outside of those scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables are specific per statement evaluated by the trigger, yes.

MERGE statements are a bit different, as the trigger will fire after each operation in the merge.

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

And specific to MERGE here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx